# Is Realm secure like SQLite & Core Data?

Tags: ios, iphone, realm

Is Realm  replacement for SQLite & Core Data,How secure it is and how to use Realm

Comment: Check the docs, https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/ , they say it is a replacement ;)

Answer (score 1):

Both `Sqlite` and `CoreData` store plain text in store if you don't tell it to encrypt, you can use encryption with both of them to make it secure. Same is the case with Realm by default it store data in plain text but you can encrypt data by code below (its taken from the Realm site)

```
// Generate a random encryption key
NSMutableData *key = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:64];
SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, key.length, (uint8_t *)key.mutableBytes);

// Open the encrypted Realm file
RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
config.encryptionKey = key;
NSError *error = nil;
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:config error:&error];
if (!realm) {
    // If the encryption key is wrong, `error` will say that it's an invalid database
    NSLog(@"Error opening realm: %@", error);
}

// Use the Realm as normal
RLMResults<Dog *> *dogs = [Dog objectsInRealm:realm where:@"name contains 'Fido'"];
```

Please visit this [link](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#encryption) to ingest more about Encryption in Realm